# ValueError at /accounts/upload_save/

Tags: python, django

I got an error,ValueError at /accounts/upload_save/
The view accounts.views.upload_save didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Always image cannot be sent normally. I wrote in views.py

```
def photo(request):
    d = {
        'photos': Post.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/profile.html', d)

def upload_save(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
     print(444)
     form = UserImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
     if form.is_valid():
        print(5555)
        image1 = form.cleaned_data.get('image1')
        image2 = form.cleaned_data.get("image2")
        user = request.user

        ImageAndUser.objects.create(
            User=user,
            image=image1,
            image2=image2,
            image3=image3,
        )
        return redirect('registration/accounts/photo.html')

    else:
        print(666)
        form = UserImageForm(request.POST or None)
        return render(request, 'registration/profile.html',{'form':form})
```

in profile.html

```
<main>
        <div>
              <img class="absolute-fill">

          <div class="container" id="photoform">

          <form action="/accounts/upload_save/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">
            {% csrf_token %}

          　　<div class="input-group">
                <label>
                    <input id="image1" type="file" name="image1" accept="image/*" style="display: none">
                </label>
          　　　 <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="">
          　　</div>

          　　<div class="input-group">
                <label>
                    <input id="image2" type="file" name="image2" accept="image/*" style="display: none">
                </label>
          　　　 <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="">
          　　</div>
          　　
          　　<div class="input-group">
                <label>
                    <input id="image3" type="file" name="image3" accept="image/*" style="display: none">
                </label>
          　　　 <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="">
          　　</div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="hidden" value="{{ p_id }}" name="p_id" class="form-control">
            </div>
              <input id="send" type="submit" value="SEND" class="form-control">

          </form>
        </div>

        </div>

        </div>
    </main>
```

in forms.py

```
class UserImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField()
    class Meta:
        model = ImageAndUser
        fields = ('image1','image2','image3')
```

in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^profile/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
    url(r'^photo/$', views.photo, name='photo'),
    url(r'^upload_save/$', views.upload_save, name='upload_save'),
]
```

I really cannot understand why this error happens.I surely send images so I think type is not None.What is wrong in my code?How should I fix this?I debuged my views.py code,so 444 is shown in print(444).Traceback is
Traceback:

```
File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  198.                 "returned None instead." % (callback.__module__, view_name)

Exception Type: ValueError at /accounts/upload_save/
Exception Value: The view accounts.views.upload_save didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Comment: post your urls.py file

Comment: Your form is invalid somehow therefore it is not going into if form.is_Valid condition.

Comment: @Exprator I added urls.py.

Comment: Why are you not using [`form.save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) to save to the model?

Comment: @mhawke How should I use  form.save() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, `image3` is not being set. Try adding this line

```
    image3 = form.cleaned_data.get("image3")
```

after the one that does the same thing for `image2`.

Further to that, the view will return `None` if the form is invalid, i.e. if `form.is_valid()` returns `False`.

Comment: I added ur code, but same error happens.What is wrong in my code?How should I fix this?

Comment: @user9287271: I don't trust that the code that you've posted is the same as you are working with, otherwise you would previously have had a `NameError` exception. Please double check the code, and double check the indentation because that also looks suspicious (the top level `if` statement seems to be indented by only 1 character)

Comment: The bottom `else` statement look like it should be aligned with the nested `if`, not the top-level one. It's out by a single space which you might not have noticed. Or maybe an error was introduced when you posted the code here?

Comment: @user9287271: not sure why you have accepted this answer. I think that [Sagar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48597314/21945) seems correct.

Answer (score 1):

couple of thing wrong in your code:

First you model looks like this: 
     Modle: ImageAndUser contain four fieds: user, image, image2, image3

as you have mentioned in object creation.
 ImageAndUser.objects.create(User=user,image=image1,image2=image2,image3=image3
        )

and you mentioned field in form:

```
class UserImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField()
    class Meta:
        model = ImageAndUser
        fields = ('image1','image2','image3')
```

where image1 is coming from. It's image attribute.

do it like this.

```
class UserImageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ImageAndUser
        fields = ('image','image2','image3')
```

Make Edit in your template side.

```
   <input id="image" type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" style="display: none">
    </label>
```

Hope this works.

Comment: This seems the likely problem. Perhaps the extra `ImageField` field should be removed because the view does not process it anyway.